# How Windows executes an Win32 process?

Tags: windows, multithreading, process, portable-executable

So when you open an PE (.exe) or call CreateProcess (from Win32 API) the following procedure is followed:

1. The file header, image sectors and also the DLL's which the exe links against are mapped into the Process Own Virtual Memory.
2. CPU begin execution at the program start address.

So here comes my question - all the instructions in the PE image use an address relative to it's own Private Address Space (Virtual Memory), which begins with 0. Also sometimes this memory is paged out by Windows somewhere in the Secondary Memory (HDD). How the CPU find out the real physical address in the RAM? Also how the Windows switch from one thread to another by it's priority, to support multi-threading and when the CPU is not fully used send Idle instructions? After all this discoveries I'm starting to think that actually the machine code, stored in the PE files, isn't really executed directly by the CPU but instead in some Windows managed environment? Can this be true, and if so doesn't this slow-down the execution?

EDIT: Ok so the question should be rewritten as follows: "Are the Windows Processes executed in an core layout program or directly on the CPU?". I get the answer I wanted, so anyway the question is solved.

Comment: I assure you that in unmanaged code, the instructions in the .exe are executed directly by the CPU.  But your question is so broad that the answer could fill several chapters of a textbook.  I suggest you narrow it down to a single focus.

Comment: @CareyGregory - depends what you mean by "directly" - a lot of modern CPUs translate the machine code into microcode sequences and then executes those :-)

Comment: Instructions are executed directly.  Download the Intel Processor Manual Volume 3 and start reading at chapter 4.  It explains how the CR3 register and the page directory and page tables work to map a virtual memory address to a physical address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A complete answer would fill an entire book, but in short:

1. From a high-level view, finding the physical address is done by dividing the address by some constant (typically 4096), converting the address to its corresponding "page", and looking up that page in a table, which points to the index of the real, physical memory page, if one exists. Some or all of that may be done automatically by the CPU without anyone noticing, depending on the situation.
   If a page does not exist, the OS will have to read the page from disk prior to letting the code that tried to access the page continue -- and not necessarily always into the same physical page.
   In reality it's **much** more complex, as the table is really an entire hierarchy of tables, and in addition there is a [small cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer) (typically around 50 entries) inside the CPU to do this task automatically for recently accessed pages, without firing an interrupt and running special kernel code.
   So, depending on the situation, things might happen fully automatically and invisibly, or the OS kernel may be called, traversing an entire hierarchy of tables, and finally resorting to loading data from disk (and I haven't even considered that pages may have protections that prevent them from being accessed, or protections that will cause them being copied when written to, etc. etc.).
2. Multi-threading is "relatively simple" in comparison. It's done by having a timer periodically fire an interrupt every so and so often (under Windwos typically around 16 milliseconds, but this can be adjusted), and running some code (the "scheduler") inside the interrupt handler which decides whether to return to the current thread or change to another thread's context and run that one instead.
   In the particular case of Windows, the scheduler will always satisfy highest priority tasks first, and only consider lower priority tasks when no non-blocked higher priority tasks are left.
   If no other tasks are running, the idle task (which has the lowest priority) runs. The idle task may perform tasks such as zeroing reclaimed memory pages "for free", or it may throttle down the CPU (or both).
   Further, when a thread blocks (e.g. when reading a file or a socket), the scheduler runs even without a timer interrupt. This ensures that the CPU can be used for something useful during the time the blocked thread can't do anything.

Comment: In any explanation of modern, multithreaded, multitasking OS scheduling/dispatching, any mention of the timer interrupt should be near the end, not at the start.  The threads are primarily used to achieve high I/O performance, not to swich between threads upon the timer interrupt.  The commonly-used terms 'quantum', 'time-slice' are hugely misleading, (yes, I don't care that M$ uses them).  It's quite possible to implement a multithreaded OS, with the high I/O performance, without any timer interrupt at all, (though the timeouts on many OS calls are obviously useful).

Comment: @MartinJames: You probably refer to the "tickless kernel" feature of Linux 3.10, which is out for about 3 months? Admittedly, it's certainly possible to do such a thing (as now proven), but it's nowhere near trivial. Also, the OP's question is specifically about Windows, so Windows behaviour is relevant. Besides, the tickless kernel still necessarily uses timer interrupts, only not at a fixed step (I'm saying this without actually having looked at the implementation, but it's hardly possible to do otherwise, unless one doesn't care about fairness).

Comment: Doing without a timer is only possible if you schedule whenever a syscall is made, or when another interrupt happens by accident (say, disk or network I/O). But then, fairness is rather "approximate" or "random". If a process does heavy number crunching without doing any syscalls, it is undeterministic whether another process will ever be scheduled, much as if the process was running with RT priority. Usually that's not acceptable, it's not very far away from cooperative multitasking.

Comment: Thanks! I'm really a lot more calm now when I know that windows core isn't running a program layer between the instructions in the PE and the CPU. The explanation with the interrupts and the CPU virtual addresses architecture management really made my day ;).

*I mean that I accept the answer - I'm not being ironic if it sounds that way.